# java: Using Buffered Reader and checking if String is null

Tags: java, null, bufferedreader

why doesn´t `if (txtLine == null)   {    break;     };`work? or maybe the correct answer is why does it still set the string `txtLine` to null (literally). The way I understand it, it should break the moment the string is null? I don´t want it to set the string to "null". but stop when there are no more lines in the *.txt file

```
try{
    BufferedReader txtReader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("test.txt"));
    while (true) {
        // Reads one line.
        println(txtLine);
        if(txtLine == null){
            break;
        };
        txtLine = txtReader.readLine();
        nLines(txtLine);
    }
    txtReader.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new ErrorException(ex);   
}
```

the `txtFile` variable is defined as an IVAR

```
private int nChars = 0;
private String txtLine = new String(); 
private ArrayList <String> array = new ArrayList <String>();
```

Comment: Where is txtLine defined ? Can you please add it to your code snippet?

Comment: If you google about reading user input through `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` in Java ->  You will immediately get `millions` of result which will clear your doubt..

Comment: I advice you to always have finally when working with IO

Comment: BTW, you could move txtLine = txtReader.readLine(); before if(txtLine == null) and println(txtLine) after if(txtLine == null)

Comment: @Lews: nLines just adds the line to an Array then returns it´s size

Comment: Convert it to try-with-resources too, then you can skip a finally block safely too. `try(BufferedReader txtReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt")))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the ordering of when you break and when you change the value of `txtLine` to be the next line read from the file is backwards, your code should look something like:

```
try{
    BufferedReader txtReader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("test.txt"));
    while (true) {
        // Reads one line.
        println(txtLine);
        txtLine = txtReader.readLine();
        // check after we read the value of txtLine
        if(txtLine == null){
            break;
        }

        nLines(txtLine);
    }
    txtReader.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new ErrorException(ex);   
}
```

But this is a much more concise (and I think, clearer) form:

```
try{
    BufferedReader txtReader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("test.txt"));
    while ((txtLine = txtReader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Reads one line.
        println(txtLine);
        nLines(txtLine);
    }
    txtReader.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new ErrorException(ex);   
}
```

Where `while ((txtLine = txtReader.readLine()) != null)` sets txtLine to the next line, and then checks that txtLine is not null before continuing.

Comment: Correct! it was the ordering of `txtLine = txtReader.readLine();`as you pointed out. Of course it needs to read the new Line to check if it is null before performing a conditional check.